# GeoServer - WMS v WFS (polygon label issue)

Tags: geoserver, polygon, wms, wfs, style

I am hoping that when I switch over to WFS that my multi-polygon labelling issue will disappear.

Currently I am using WMS, and I believe the reason I am seeing multiple labels within my polygons is because each tile is being rendered in its own silo. Therefore the server thinks that there needs to be a label for each tile inside a given polygon.

I know there are the centroid solutions, except that solution does not work for me since I want the labels inside the polygon and not in space outside a non-symmetric polygon.

Will WFS solve this issue?

Comment: A WMS doesn't have tiles, so perhaps the issue is the client making tile like requests

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the centroid function use the [pole of inaccessibility](https://blog.ianturton.com/geoserver/styling/2016/08/30/Polygon-Labelling-in-GeoServer.html) function which will force the label to fall within the polygon.